# Deploying WCF Service in Windows Service with pipes getting 'System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException'

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

We've created a WCF service that is hosted as a Windows Service.  Our service is installed with our application on a computer, and it will never be accessed remotely from other clients.  So, we've designed it to use named pipes...  On our development computer, it works perfectly when we install and run our service and application.  However, when we deploy our application and service to a test computer and run it, we get an SecurityNegotiationException, which is due to a call that our application makes to the service when it launches.  If I comment out this service call, our application loads and run properly, as long as it doesn't use the service.  I've scoured the Internet to see how to resolve this issue, but I couldn't find anything that deals specifically with WCF + Windows Service + named pipes.  I really would appreciate your help!

Thanks,

## Mike

## EXCEPTION

Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException
Stack:

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUpgrade(Stream stream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection& connection, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
   at ClientSaver.MainForm..ctor()
   at ClientSaver.Program.Main()

=========================================================

## SERVICE'S APP.CONFIG FILE

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="" name="ClientSaver.VssService.VssService">
            <endpoint address="Pipe" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="" contract="ClientSaver.VssService.IVssService" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/VssService/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>      
</system.serviceModel>
```

===========================================================

## === CLIENT'S WCF INFORMATION FROM ITS APP.CONFIG         ==

```
    <bindings>
          <netNamedPipeBinding>
                <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IVssService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                      transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                      maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                      <security mode="Transport">
                            <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                      </security>
                </binding>
          </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
          <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/VssService/Pipe" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IVssService" contract="VssService.IVssService"
                name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IVssService">
                <identity>
                      <servicePrincipalName value="host/DEVPC_W7.aboh.local" />
                </identity>
          </endpoint>
    </client>
    <services>
        <service name="ClientSaver.VssService.VssService">
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="" contract="ClientSaver.VssService.IVssService" />

            <endpoint address="http://localhost/VssService/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="" contract="ClientSaver.VssService.IVssService" />                            
        </service>
    </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="VssServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>      
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Can you please give us the associated error message and the inner exception if any?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

When using the NetNamedPipeBinding, Transport security is configured by default. This causes a security negotiation between the client and service channel stacks when the channel is opened. Your exception is occurring during initiation of this negotiation. (See [here](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2010/11/04/talking-to-wcf-over-named-pipes-1-the-framing-protocol.aspx) for more detail on how this happens.)

Please could you provide details of how your WCF client is configured. The value of the exception's Message property would also be valuable diagnostic information. My guess is that there is some mismatch between the configuration of security on the client side and the default configuration shown for the Service.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am traveling until Friday, but I will try to remotely debug the application and see if I can get more exception information. I've ensured that VS2010 generated a current interface to our WCF service. Previously, I posted the service's app.config file. I will post the client app.config file since it may contain a hint as to what is wrong. I'd appreciate it if you could please take a look at it. It contains Enterprise Logging as well as the generated WCF code.  Thanks for your help!  --Mike

Comment: I strongly suspect that everything will work if you remove the whole of the <identity> element from the client endpoint config.

Comment: More accurately: I strongly suspect that the <identity> element in the client endpoint config is not correct for the machine it is running on. I have confirmed that this would cause a SecurityNegotiationException with a message saying "The server has rejected the client credentials". Why do you need to specify identity? Removing it completely may fix your problem.

Comment: Hi Chris, I will try your idea tomorrow when I return to the office.  <identity> element was autogenerated by VS2010 when I told my Service Reference to update from our WCF Windows Service.  Is there a way to tell it not to add this element when generating the client interface code, or should I create some matching element in the service app.config?  In an hour I will be back in the hotel and can check the WCF book that I have with me.  Thank you for your suggestion! -- Mike

Comment: So, I told one of our Developers to remove the <Identity> element and redeploy our application to a test computer.  He reported that the Event Log is now showing a file not found exception when the application is launched.  So, I will need to do a remote debugging session to see what is going on.  I suspect that removing the <identity> tag worked, and now we've found a .dll that is not in the installer.  I'll post an update tomorrow when I can debug things.

Comment: On another note...  I am thinking that I really need to implement the <identity> element and have some form of basic authentication between the client and service.  In our released application, we disable MEX and only the Pipe is available for connections, but we should have basic authentication in order to prohibt unauthorized use of the service.  So... In the long run, I probably need to implement authentication.

Comment: The thing that I find very curious, is why the application would work fine on our development computer with the <Identity> element in place, but fails on deployment...  Anyway, I will post an update tomorrow.  Thanks again for the heads-up!  -- Mike

Comment: So, I remotely connected from my hotel room and removed the <Identity> tag from the WCF Service.  I also looked at the client's app.config file again, and found that its <servicePrincipalName was for a different computer.  When I changed it to the local computer on which the application and service are installed, the exception that we have been chasing disappeared!

Comment: So, I think that we have found the culprit!  I am going to do some research on how to provide basic authentication for our service, but now I can move on.  THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 0):

The named pipe binding is used only for in-proc service / client. It means that the service and the client must be on the same computer.

Try to use TcpBinding instead if you have both the client and the service developed with WCF.

Comment: Hi, As I mentioned in my description, the service and the application are installed on the same computer, so named pipes should work.

Comment: Hi, there isn't any inner exception...  I am still searching on the Net to figure out why I am getting this SecurityNegotiationException.  All the examples that I have seen using pipes don't require authentication.